# Testing for delay time in a request

Tags: python, tcp, ip, scapy, ttl

I am interested in being able to detect specific parameters using the loading time it took a request from when I send it to when it got to the server. 
The request I am talking about is the SYN packet in a three way hand shake.
How can I do this?
Looking forward to your answer! 
Of course also what language should I use...I am testing with Python + Scapy right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Scapy (which seems a reasonable choice for what you want to do), you need to use the `Packet.time` attribute. Here is a simple example:

```py
>>> def measure_delay(packet):
...     ans, _ = sr(packet, verbose=False)
...     if ans:
...         return reduce(lambda x, y: y.time - x.time, ans[0])
... 
>>> measure_delay(IP(dst='192.168.1.254')/TCP(dport=80))
0.07259798049926758
```

From a Unix command line, you can also use hping3, and look for the `rtt=` value:

```
# sudo hping3 --syn 192.168.1.254 -p 80 -c 1
HPING 192.168.1.254 (wlan0 192.168.1.254): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=44 ip=192.168.1.254 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=80 flags=SA seq=0 win=14600 rtt=3.1 ms

--- 192.168.1.254 hping statistic ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 3.1/3.1/3.1 ms
```

Comment: Thank you!! But what do you think about using the pkt.time option?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Using `Packet.time` attribute is the good way to do what you want in Scapy, I only mention the hping3 solution for the record.